# Using an interface class as member type in another class

Tags: c++, visual-c++, design-patterns

I'm trying to design a piece of code that entails the use of an algorithm. The algorithm should be easily replaceable by someone else in the future. So in my **LargeClass** there has to be a way to invoke a specific algorithm.

I provided some example code below. My idea was to make an interface class **IAlgorithm** so that you have to provide an implementation yourself. I thought you could initialize it to which ever derived class you wanted in the constructor of the **LargeClass**. However the below code doesn't compile in VS2015 because `IAlgorithm: cannot instantiate abstract class`

**My question:** How should I design this in order to get the result I want?

Thanks in advance!

**Algorithm.h**

```
class IAlgorithm
{
protected:
    virtual int Algorithm(int, int) = 0;
};

class algo1 : public IAlgorithm
{
public:
    virtual int Algorithm(int, int);
};

class algo2 : public IAlgorithm
{
public:
    virtual int Algorithm(int, int);
};
```

**Algorithm.cpp**

```
#include "Algorithm.h"

int algo1::Algorithm(const int a, const int b)
{
    // Do something
}

int algo2::Algorithm(const int a, const int b)
{
    // Do something
}
```

**Source.cpp**

```
#include "Algorithm.h"

class LargeClass
{

private:
    IAlgorithm algo;
};

int main()
{


}
```

Comment: Use a reference or pointer for the member.

Comment: "How should I design this in order to get the result I want?" - the question is, what result do you really want? I mean, you've made a decision to use a polymorphic algorithm, but why? What's the end result we're looking for? I ask this because polymorphic interfaces are often the most inflexible, and have been largely deprecated in favour of lambdas, closures and templates.

Comment: You have not thought enough about how you are going to create and destroy the *specific* implementation of the interface.  You are asking the compiler to do it for you and it correctly complains that it doesn't know how to do that.  Right now your code does not have an oracle that gives you the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My first thoughts on this would be, why use such a primitive interface?

OK, we have a requirement that some process needs an algorithm sent into it. This algorithm must be polymorphic, it must take two ints and return an int.

All well and good. There is already a construct for this in the standard library. It's call a `std::function`. This is a wrapper around any function object with a compatible interface.

example:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

class LargeClass
{
  public:

  using algorithm_type = std::function<int(int,int)>;

  LargeClass(algorithm_type algo)
  : _algo(std::move(algo))
  {}

  int apply(int x, int y) {
    return _algo(x,y);
  }

private:
    algorithm_type _algo;
};

int test(LargeClass&& lc) {
  return lc.apply(5,5);
}

int divide(int x, int y) { return x / y; }

int main()
{
  // use a lambda
  std::cout << test(LargeClass{ [](auto x,auto y){ return x + y; } });

  // use a function object
  std::cout << test(LargeClass{ std::plus<>() } );

  // use a free function
  std::cout << test(LargeClass{ divide } );

  // use a function object

  struct foo_type {
    int operator()(int x, int y) const {
      return x * 2 + y;
    }
  } foo;
  std::cout << test(LargeClass{ foo_type() } );
  std::cout << test(LargeClass{ foo } );

}
```

Comment: Thanks for providing such a nice answer